# Writing a Typescript Library with a Web Assembly Dependency?

Tags: javascript, typescript, browser, webassembly

I'm planning on writing a typescript library for distributions on that will depend on [`cephes`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cephes).

In order for the web assembly to be used in the browser we have to compile it like this:

```
const cephes = require('cephes'); // Browser
await cephes.compiled;
```

I'm not sure how to go about implementing this for a Typescript library that is wrapping cephes.

For example the library will supply a NormalDistribution that could be imported like this:

```
import { NormalDistrbution } from 'cephesdistributions';
```

If we do tree shaking then NormalDistribution may be the only import included from the package.  Do we therefore need to include `await cephes.compiled` in all of the modules offered by `cephesdistributions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be as straightforward as possible. Since your consumers can't really get around having to `await`, I would suggest that you leave it to your consumers to `await cephes.compiled`.

If you're bundling `cephes`, you might want to re-export `cephes.compiled` from your library so that your consumers can just use your library:

```js
const cephes = require('cephes');

export const compiled = cephes.compiled;

export class NormalDistribution {
  public mean: number;
  public sd: number;

  constructor(mean = 0, sd = 1) {
    this.mean = mean;
    this.sd = 1;
  }

  cdf(x: number): number {
    // If this gets called before someone has `await`:ed `compiled`
    // there will be trouble.
    return cephes.ndtr(x);
  }
}
```

This means that your exported classes will have their types immediately available, even if they would crash if called too early. Since your consumers are as dependent on `cephes.compiled` being resolved as you are, you could consider storing the state of compilation and "guarding" where appropriate. For example,

```js
const cephes = require('cephes');

let isCompiled = false;
export function assertIsCompiled() {
  if (isCompiled) {
    return;
  }

  throw new Error('You must wait for `cephesdistributions.compiled` to resolve');
}

export const compiled = cephes.compiled.then(() => { isCompiled = true });

export class NormalDistribution {
  public mean: number;
  public sd: number;

  constructor(mean = 0, sd = 1) {
    assertIsCompiled();

    this.mean = mean;
    this.sd = 1;
  }

  cdf(x: number): number {
    return cephes.ndtr(x);
  }
}
```

Comment: Great explanation - I love the assertIsCompiled() technique!